# What's the difference between cron and services like Supervisord?

Tags: cron, scheduled-task, background-process, supervisord

Recently I came across supervisor while researching beanstalk stuff. Can someone explain to me why I might use a process management service like that instead of plain old cron jobs?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that both services have quite different purposes: With `cron` you start typically short jobs at regular intervals while `supervisor` can be used to control the existence of typically long-running server processes and it's dependencies.

I.e. you could run a web server with `supervisor`, but would handle log rotation with `logrotate` from  a `cron` job.

Comment: That makes sense. Have you used beanstalk at all? Basically, it's a messaging queue you can monitor and process tasks with. Based off that, would you think that'd be best run with a cron job that just checks the queue every X minutes or as a process that is constantly checking it? Does it depend how often I need this queue to be executed? Is a corn job every second basically the same as having a process?